Restore-DbaDatabase - restore specific database from backup-folder
I am trying to restore a single database from a backup-share with multiple backup-files.
I have three files in c:\backups\

db1.bak
db2.bak
db3.bak

I am using Restore-DbaDatabase in powershell.
This is my command:
Restore-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance localhost -Path "${backupFilePath}" -WithReplace 

I couldn't find any parameter where I can specify only to restore File 'db3.bak'.
Is there any way?
Thanks in advance.
Best regards

Have you tried passing the file path, rather than the path to the directory? $backupFilePath = "C:\backups\db3.bak"

Hi Mathias, thank you very much, it works fine.

The -Path parameter takes one or more paths - but it doesn't have to a directory path, you can pass a leaf path just as well, and Restore-DbaDatabase will attempt to restore only that:
$backupFilePath = "C:\backups\db3.bk"
Restore-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance localhost -Path $backupFilePath -WithReplace 

Another approach is to user PowerShell's existing provider item cmdlets (Get-Item, Get-ChildItem) to discover the file(s) on disk and then piping the file objects to Restore-DbaBatabase:
$relevantBackupFiles = Get-Item -LiteralPath C:\backups\db3.bak
$relevantBackupFiles |Restore-DbaDatabase -SqlInstance localhost -WithReplace 

